# Как сделать покупку Pro-версии приложения через PayPal?

Tags: android, paypal

Есть приложение в двух версиях - Pro и Free. Переход от Free к Pro делается за небольшую сумму денег от пользователя с помощью in-app платежа. Раньше это было реализовано с помощью Google, потом они забанили мой аккаунт. Поэтому теперь я хочу сделать это, используя PayPal.

Вопрос: как реализовать единоразовую покупку через PayPal? Фактически, кроме покупки, нужно реализовать проверку, что юзер уже купил Pro-версию. Как это проверить? Предоставляет ли PayPal такой функционал?

Comment: Хранить транзакции на своём сервере.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а как идентифицировать пользователя?

Comment: Авторизацию через свой сервер делать, например. Или через любую соц. сеть, но сохранять на своём сервере идентификатор юзера из этой соц. сети и к ней привязывать потом транзакции.

Comment: А зачем соц. сети, если абсолютно все пользователи Google Play(GP) имеют аккаунты в этом магазине. Без аккаунтов нельзя скачать приложение из GP.
Но это лишь на случай распространения только в GP.

Comment: @web_alex, придется тогда лишнее разрешение на чтение аккаунтов добавлять, нехорошо. В идеале бы наверное к PayPal аккаунту и привязывать.